# code for subtracting 1 from a digit stored in an array using c

Tags: c++

can any one help me with code that subtract 1 from a digit stored in an array using c++ (elementary mathematics)
eg..
100-1=99
and 
98-1=97

Comment: I don't think "digit" is the word you're looking for.  Can you better explain your problem?

Comment: i from a number the digits of which are stored in a number..

Comment: I'll ask the studip question:  Why would you store the digits in an array?

Comment: @alabamasucks: Probably because it's a homework exercise, and those frequently seem silly to experienced programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have stored the digits in an array, you'll need to follow your elementary-school math on the array from right to left.  "Borrow" from the next place to the left as needed.

Comment: Please don't do their homework for them. Just give them enough to be able to think it through themselves. If you give them all the answers, they don't learn anything and we end up with lots of bad code to fix and maintain later.

Comment: thanx but not this one for example i have the nuber 9999870 whose digits are stored in array i want to subtract 1 from this number which will give 9999869 using elementary mathmatics

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was homework...  It doesn't seem like that constitutes a down vote.

Comment: @jheddings: I didn't downvote you. I just made the suggestion about not providing homework answers.

Comment: No worries, not sure who did (doesn't really matter). I was just trying to understand why it was down-voted.